# Expected ',' seperator and expected ')' in expression list

Tags: json, swift, nserror

I received two errors from the script below:

```
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)



        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                if let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    print(parseJSON)

                    let resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String
                    print("Result: \(resultValue)")
                    print(userEmail)
                    print(userPassword)


                    var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true; }

                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    if(!isUserRegistered)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        //Display alert message with confirmation
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Alert", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){

                            action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);

                        }

                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
                        )};
                }
            }
        catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

The first error was this: `Expected ',' seperator` on this line:

```
 )};
```

Its says to `insert ","` but its a continual error and it doesn't end.

On the next line below, which is just a bracket `}`, I get the error: `Expected ')' in the expression list`

Comment: You want `})`, not `)}` (or you could use trailing closure syntax). Also note you don't need semi-colons at the end of lines,  nor parentheses around your `if` conditions.

Comment: Swift is **not** a *scripting* language (unlike PHP) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

}) not )}

```
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)



    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(parseJSON)

                let resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String
                print("Result: \(resultValue)")
                print(userEmail)
                print(userPassword)


                var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
                if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true; }

                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                if(!isUserRegistered)
                {
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    //Display alert message with confirmation
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Alert", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){

                        action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);

                    }

                    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
                });
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}

 }
```